# spring neo4j movie example cannot add new node

Tags: spring, spring-data-neo4j

I am new to neo4j making understanding using available example project SDN4 university "https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4". In same project added new node named as 'Link' also having relationship with movie node. After adding additional node and relationship with movie getting below error:

> Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.502 sec <<< FAILURE! - in movie.repositories.MovieRepositoryTest
>   testFindByTitle(movie.repositories.MovieRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.36 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of movie.domain.Movie; nested exception is org.neo4j
>   .ogm.exception.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of movie.domain.Movie
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie{
    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    @Relationship(type = "MOVIE_LINK", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NodeEntity
public class Link{
@Relationship(type = "MOVIE_LINK")
    private Movie movie = new Movie();
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "MOVIE_LINK")
public class MovieLink
{
    public MovieLink(Movie movie, Link link){
    super();
    this.movie = movie;
    this.link = link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes for both node and relationship entities must have a no argument public constructor so OGM can instantiate the entity.